# Angular 2 Router, href links and unwanted page refresh

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-routing

i am currently experimenting with angular2 (beta1) and i'm a bit puzzled about the new router.

Navigating via router.navigate works like a charm, while trying to do that via a normal link to a registered route refreshes the page.
This happens with PathLocationStrategy of course, as HashLocationStrategy works as expected.

Is this a bug or the normal behaviour?

TIA

Comment: Can you please show some code or a plunker?

Answer (score 7):

You should use a `routerLink` instead. For example `<a [routerLink]="[ '/MyCmp', {myParam: 'value' } ]">`

See also https://angular.io/guide/ajs-quick-reference#ng-href

You could add event listeners to the `<a href=...` elements or a parent and call `router.navigate...` and `event.preventDefault()`.

Comment: I thought so. The problem is that i might need links in html text loaded from external JSONs and it has to be vanilla html. In angular 1.x worked fine :(

Comment: `routerLink` will also give you nightmares when trying to make a crawlable site (SEO).

Comment: @displayname are there any alternatives for SPAs and pushstate that don't cause such SEO issues?

Comment: I don't have deep knowledge here, but I think this is just how browsers pushstate works, to get the URL updated without full page reload. I'd guess a sitemap with supported URLs should allow crawlers to figure out what to index.

Comment: Aaas it turns out you're right so I have to take back what I said about Angular. This is standard HTML-behavior. My statement about `routerLink` is still true unfortunately and yes, generating sitemaps definitely helps. Nevertheless it's nice if it's not necessary having to do that as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can try passing the json in the html template on routerLink like this.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `
    <a [routerLink]="routerData">
  `
})
class AppComponent {
  this.routeData = [ '/MyCmp', {myParam: 'value' } ]
}
```

If you have array of link you can still try something like this with *ngFor