# UI-router reloads page on href link click

Tags: angular-ui-router

I'm migrating my angularJS application with `ui-router` to angular 4 with `@uirouter/angular`.

I see different behaviour when it comes to links created not via `uiSref` directive. In `@uirouter/angular` they reload entire page. Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/bF7c29SU1j83opj53Ulc

What is the best workaround to navigate and not reload page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, it is problem with angular 2+ itself: [Angular 2 Router, href links and unwanted page refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34787262/angular-2-router-href-links-and-unwanted-page-refresh)

I've wrote small script to fix it: https://gist.github.com/Polvista/b19054c705859cef8e38c70de4cf29f8